# Firefox 14.0.1 - Windows - Font not work - Bad URI or cross-site access not allowed error

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

How to fix this error:

```
[06:31:06.469] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "kidss" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: <a href="http://www.mysite.pl/fonts/kidss.ttf" target="_blank">http://www.mysite.pl/fonts/kidss.ttf</a> @ <a href="http://www.mysite.pl/style.css" target="_blank">http://www.mysite.pl/style.css</a>
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Put the font in your own website and use a relative url.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw an absolute url. In that case, verify that the url is indeed relative and valid. The url in your post is not.

Comment: it worked only  for a moment,but now i've got again a problem with it. Firefox block my url with font?

Comment: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting?

Comment: If the font is on the same site as the page requesting it there is no cross site scripting issue, because there is no cross site situation at all. Can you give a link to the page causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Check your domain settings. If you're going to myfancysite.net, and you aren't being redirected to www.myfancysite.net this is likely your issue. We've found that Firefox 14 has some strange exception for @font-face kits related to unqualified domains. On our sites that automatically redirect to the qualified URL, we don't see this issue in FF14.

EDIT: This issue seems to affect FF14 Windows 32-bit and FF14 Mac 32- and 64-bit. FF14 64-bit for Win7 will automatically bounce to the qualified domain.

EDIT 2: We did some more testing and this also seems to occur in IE9.